# Adding some figures/numbers on the colored map with map.text

Tags: r, maps

I am struggling with adding text on a map, which I built with `map.text` function.

I colored my states, as I wish, but now, I also want to add some numbers/figures on the states, on the map.

This is the code that I’ve used to have it:

```
library(“maps”)


win.obama = c( "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "District of Columbia",
               "Delaware", "Florida", "Hawaii", "Iowa" ,               
               "Illinois", "Massachusetts",  "Maryland", "Maine" ,              
               "Michigan", "Minnesota",   "New Hampshire", "New Jersey",          
               "New Mexico", "Nevada",   "New York",   "Ohio",           
               "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "Virginia",           
               "Vermont", "Washington", "Wisconsin")

win.romney = c("Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "Arizona", "Georgia", "Idaho",         
               "Indiana", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Missouri", "Mississippi",   
               "Montana", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Nebraska", "Oklahoma", "South Carolina",
               "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "West Virginia", "Wyoming")

map(database = "state")

map(database = "state", regions = win.obama, col = "blue", fill=T, add=TRUE)

map(database = "state", regions = win.romney, col = "red2", fill=T, add=TRUE)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: with `map.text` ? (`map.text(database="state", region="Alabama", labels="Ala", add=TRUE)` for example)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map.text` to put text on the map in the different regions:

For example:

```
map.text(database="state", region="Alabama", labels="Ala", add=TRUE)
```

See `?map.text` for details about the function.

As a side note, you can display your map with one call with:

```
map(database="state", regions=c(win.obama, win.romney), col=rep(c("blue", "red2"), c(length(win.obama), length(win.romney))), fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: Your single statement for generating the map is nice, but it is not producing the same result as OP's three statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It really helped a lot.

@Cath, but how ? Why these regions are affecting the colors ?

Comment: @ErenB the colors are a vector of same size as the regions, but for that I think regions need to be properly defined as in exact same name as regions in the database, otherwise, it results in a shift.

Comment: @Cath So, then i am totally lost now; it's my second week with R and i am little bit struggling.